# Errors when trying to bring up docker-compose

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

Has anyone seen the below errors before? I can't figure out why they are appearing when trying to bring up docker-compose. Permissions look ok on the hosts and resolv.conf files but not sure if the are red herrings.

```
[centos@STG-WEB02 ~]$ sudo docker-compose up -d
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:33: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in the next release.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
Starting 179aa43c273c_compose_datadog-agent_1 ... error
Starting compose_frontend_1            ...

ERROR: for 179aa43c27_datadog-agent_1  Cannot start service datadog-agent: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/179aa43c273c384/hosts" to rootfs at "/etc/hosts": possibly malicious path detected -- refusing to operate on
Starting compose_search-frontend_1            ... error

ERROR: for search-frontend_1  Cannot start service search-frontend: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/2b5296bf12c1c3aef/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": possibly malicious path detected -- refusing to operate on /etc/resolv.conf: unknown

ERROR: for frontend  Cannot start service frontend: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/2b5296bf12c1c3233aef/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": possibly malicious path detected -- refusing to operate on /etc/resolv.conf: unknown

ERROR: for datadog-agent  Cannot start service datadog-agent: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/docker/containers/179aa43c273/hosts" to rootfs at "/etc/hosts": possibly malicious path detected -- refusing to operate on /etc/hosts: unknown
```

Docker version

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           23.0.3
 API version:       1.40 (downgraded from 1.42)
 Go version:        go1.19.7
 Git commit:        3e7cbfd
 Built:             Tue Apr  4 22:04:18 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.4
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.10
  Git commit:       9013bf583a
  Built:            Fri Oct 18 15:50:54 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.20
  GitCommit:        2806fc1057397dbaeefbea0e4e17bddfbd388f38
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.5
  GitCommit:        v1.1.5-0-gf19387a
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```